# Как навесить событие на кнопку?

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, метрики

Есть форма с кнопкой,вот код инпута

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-middle btn-action" value="Отправить" data-ng-click="callback.send()" data-ng-disabled="modalCallbackForm.$invalid" />
```

мне нужно повесть обработчик события для этой кнопки для яндекс метрики и roistatGoal добавляю код

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-middle btn-action" value="Отправить" onclick="yaCounter40080335.reachGoal('Buy');roistatGoal.reach({name: name, phone: phone, email: email, text: "Заказ из корзины"});return true;"  data-ng-click="callback.send()" data-ng-disabled="modalCallbackForm.$invalid" />'
```

и перестает работать,в чем проблема?может из за data-ng-click?и правильно ли навесил события?
причем инпут формируется в какой то непонятно ангуляровской функции

```
; (function (ng) {
'use strict';

var callbackService = function ($http, modalService) {
    var service = this;

    service.send = function (name, phone, comment) {

        return $http.post('callback/addcallback', { name: name, phone: phone, comment: comment, rnd: Math.random() }).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    };

    service.getParams = function () {

        return $http.get('callback/getparams').then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    };

    service.dialogRender = function (title, parentScope) {

        var options = {
            'modalClass': 'callback-dialog',
            'isOpen': true
        };

        modalService.renderModal(
            'modalCallback',
            title,
            '<div data-ng-include="\'/modules/callback/scripts/templates/modal.html\'"></div>',
            '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-middle btn-action" value="Отправить" data-ng-click="callback.send()" data-ng-disabled="modalCallbackForm.$invalid" />',
            options,
            { callback: parentScope });
    };

    service.dialogOpen = function () {
        modalService.open('modalCallback');
    };

    service.dialogClose = function () {
        modalService.close('modalCallback');
    };

    service.setVisibleFooter = function (visible) {
        modalService.setVisibleFooter('modalCallback', visible);
    };
};

ng.module('callback')
  .service('callbackService', callbackService);

callbackService.$inject = ['$http', 'modalService'];
```

})(window.angular);

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вынести все обращения из `onclick` в обработчик `data-ng-click`, прямо в контроллере. И все отправки метрики желательно оборачивать в try-catch, чтобы сбор статистики при падении не повлиял на общую работу системы.

Comment: Немного уточню,при нажатии кнопки открывается всплывающая форма с кнопкой на которую я вешаю событие,если я это событие добавляю то форма перестает открываться.

выносил свой добавленный код в data-ng-click все равно не работает .А что вы имеете в виду под оборачивать?

Comment: @Виктор а в консоль что-нибудь падает при клике?

Comment: ничего не падает,вот тестовая копия сайта на которой правлю http://test.saas_97145_afbwmxolyw-graf1987.on-advantshop.net  на главной странице есть с верху с права обратный звонок и всплывает окно на кнопку отправить надо навесить событие

Comment: @Виктор А Вы пробовали вызывать эти события не по клике на кнопку, а на `ng-submit`? По факту, как я понял, вся логика срабатывает по отправке сообщения.

Comment: не срабатывает и кстати заметил что в консоли появляется ошибка callback.js:123 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: @Виктор сейчас все отработало, видимо в этом была проблема

Comment: это я сейчас пробую и так и сяк,но все же это не привильно,вот что мне написали на другом форуме
Тебе нужно создать контроллерИ в этот контроллер инджектишь свой callbackService, далее обворачиваешь функции сервиса и выводишь их в хтмл